# Stop the running function completely when click on Stop button

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I have list of URLs to be scraped. I get these URLs from a html table and in a controller function I put them in a foreach loop. I have two buttons Start scraping and Stop scraping.

I am running with a scraping function which is written in controller and called by an ajax function on a button click of Start scraping button.

Now my requirement is to stop the current ongoing process when I click on Stop scraping button.

I have googled a lot and tried use of Gloabal variables , sessions etc etc but all this works only after the completion of first process that comes in pending state un network.

Please help me that how can I stop the current php process when I click on Stop scraping button.

Below is the ajax call function for Start scraping

```
$("#get_data").click(function()
    {
        var values = new Array();
        $.each($("input[name='case[]']:checked"), function() 
        {
            var data = $(this).parents('tr:eq(0)');
            values.push({ 
                'weburl':$(data).find('td:eq(3)').text() , 
                'id' : $(data).find('td:eq(2)').text() , 
                'state':$(data).find('td:eq(6)').text()
            });
        });
        sendmyarray(values);
    });

    function sendmyarray(values)
    {
       var location = '<?php echo base_url()?>';
       var x = $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: location+'admin/AdminController/getArrayAndScrap',
            data: {myData:JSON.stringify(values)},
            beforeSend: function() { 
                $("#stop_get_data").css("display", "block");
                $("#get_data").prop('disabled', true); // disable button
            },
            success: function (response) {   
                $("#get_data").prop('disabled', false);
                $("#stop_get_data").css("display", "none");
                console.log(response);
                if(response == 'stop')
                {
                    alert("Process Stopped");
                }   
                if(response == " ends")
                {
                    alert("Process completed. Please check the status of the URLs processed!");
                }
                
            }
        });
    }
```

// BElow is the controller function //
//-- Function to get the array of selected row's url and state ; and scraping them accordingly

```
public function getArrayAndScrape()
        {
            if(isset($_POST['myData']))
            {
                $json = $_POST['myData'];
                $myDataArray = json_decode($json,true);
                foreach ($myDataArray as $url) 
                {
                    $status = $this->CommonModel->getSingleData('dtl_scrap_status','ws_detail',array('dtl_scrap_id' => $url['id']));

                    if( $status['dtl_scrap_status'] != 'Scrapped')
                    {
                        $ch = curl_init();
                        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
                        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
                        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 12); // 12 seconds
                        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url['weburl']);
                        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

                        $html = curl_exec($ch);
                        if($html === false)
                        {
                            $this->CommonModel->addData('ws_detail' , array('dtl_scrap_status' => curl_error($ch) , 'dtl_scrap_id' => $url['id'] , 'dtl_state' => $url['state'] , 'dtl_website' => $url['weburl']));
                            $this->CommonModel->updateData('ws_site_scrap_detail' , array('site_last_scrap_date' => date('Y-m-d')) , array('site_id' => $url['id']));
                    }
                        else
                        {
                            $doc = new DOMDocument();
                            @$doc->loadHTML($html);
                            
                            $nodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('title'); // TITLE
                            $metas = $doc->getElementsByTagName('meta'); // Meta
                            $head = $doc->getElementsByTagName('h1'); // H1

                            if(isset($nodes->item(0)->nodeValue))
                            {
                                $title = $nodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
                            }

                            if(isset($head->item(0)->nodeValue))
                            {
                                $heading = $head->item(0)->nodeValue;
                            }

                            if(isset($metas))
                            {
                                for ($i = 0; $i < $metas->length; $i++)
                                {
                                    $meta = $metas->item($i);
                                    if($meta->getAttribute('name') == 'keywords') // Keyword
                                    $keywords = $meta->getAttribute('content');

                                    if($meta->getAttribute('name') != '')
                                    {
                                        if($meta->getAttribute('name') == 'description') // meta description
                                        {
                                           $description = $meta->getAttribute('content');
                                        }
                                    }elseif($meta->getAttribute('property') != '')
                                    {
                                        if($meta->getAttribute('property') == 'og:description') // meta Og:description
                                        {
                                            $OgDescription = $meta->getAttribute('content');
                                        }
                                    }
                                }   
                            }
                            curl_close($ch);

                            if(isset($url['state']))
                            {
                                $addDtl['dtl_state'] = $url['state'];
                            }
                            if(isset($heading))
                            {
                                $addDtl['dtl_program_name'] = $heading;
                            }
                            if(isset($title))
                            {
                                $addDtl['dtl_program_provider'] = $title;
                            }
                            if(isset($description))
                            {
                                $addDtl['dtl_program_description'] = $description;
                            }elseif(isset($OgDescription))
                            {
                                $addDtl['dtl_program_description'] = $OgDescription;
                            }
                            if(isset($keywords))
                            {
                                $addDtl['dtl_program_keywords'] = $keywords;
                            }
                            if(isset($url['weburl']))
                            {
                                $addDtl['dtl_website'] = $url['weburl'];
                            }
                            if(isset($url['id']))
                            {
                                $addDtl['dtl_scrap_id'] = $url['id'];
                            }
                            $addDtl['dtl_scrap_status'] = 'Scrapped';
                            if($this->CommonModel->addData('ws_detail' , $addDtl))
                            {
                                $this->CommonModel->updateData('ws_site_scrap_detail' , array('site_last_scrap_date' => date('Y-m-d')) , array('site_id' => $url['id']));
                            }else
                            {
                                // echo "Error";exit();
                            }                   
                        } // End of else    
                        
                    } // End of status check
                    else
                    {
                        $this->CommonModel->updateData('ws_site_scrap_detail' , array('site_last_scrap_date' => date('Y-m-d')) , array('site_id' => $url['id']));
                        // echo "alscrapped";exit();
                    }
                } // End of foreach
                echo "ends";
            } // End of if(isset)
        }
```

// Something I want below scenario (AJAX CALL)//

```
$('#stop_get_data').click(function()
    {
        return false (from the function which is in running state after click event of start scraping);
    });
```

Any help would be important for me.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to terminate a php script with javascript. The PHP script will continue running its loop until it finishes. PHP executes on the server side while javascript is executed on the browser. There may be a way to do something like this with sockets but I really don't know enough about them to give you any advice on how to go about it.

What you could do is run the loops on the javascript side and make individual calls to the php function for each iteration. This would allow you to stop the process with javascript whenever you like.

Comment: Thanks but cannot do that.
Can you please tell me how can I call a php library function through javascript. For ex: I have a multitask library and I want to call the function do_in_background of this multitask library so how can I call this function though JS on button click
I am using something like below but its not working.
    $('#stop_get_data').click(function(){
        <?php
            $this->multitask->do_in_background(base_url().'index.php/admin/AdminController/setDbFlagVal', array('flagVal' => false));
        ?>
    });
Please help!